# How to get the prediction of new data by LSTM in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

This is a univariate time series prediction problem. As the following code shows, I divide the initial data into a train dataset (`trainX`) and a test dataset(`testX`), then I create a LSTM network by keras. Next, I train the model by the train dataset. However, when I want to get the prediction, I need to know the test value, so my problem is: why do I have to predict since I have known the true value which is test dataset in this problem. What I want to get is the prediction value of future time? If I have some misunderstandings about LSTM network, please tell me.

Thank you!

```
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
```

Comment: Machine learning is to find the function that returns y if given X. X may be the Chinese Sentences while y is the translated sentences in English. Test model is used to evaluate whether the model is good enough. So next time, when you give it another X (a new Chinese  sentence for example), it will predict the y (an English one).

Comment: You might be referring to "generative models"?  This is pretty complicated to implement.

Comment: `testPrediction = model.predict(testX)`    

the `testX` is the known dataset which is apparently used to evaluate the model while I want to get the prediction value of the time after `testX`. How can I make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why do I have to predict since I have known the true value which is test dataset in this problem. What I want to get is the prediction value of future time?

In ML, we give test data X and it returns us Y. In the case of time-series, it may mislead a beginner a bit as we use the X and output is apparently X as well: The difference here is that we are inputting old values of time-series as X and the output Y is value of same time-series but we are predicting in future (can be applied for present or even past as well) as you have identified it correctly.

*(P.S: I would recommend you to begin with simple regression and then come to LSTMs etc. if all you want is to learn the Machine Learning.)*

Comment: I truly know your meaning, and understand the process when LSTM network is learning. Maybe I didn't make the problem clear before. In fact, I know how to train a LSTM network, but have trouble in the prediction of new data. It is more important for us to get the future value to service for other usages. I just have questions on how to predict instead of evaluating the model. I don't mean evaluation is unimportant, in other words, the prediction value can take effect while the model pass the evaluation.

Comment: Ok I got you. Then use `model.predict(testX)` only. Actually this is what we do in the case of *most* of Deep Learning models which are pre-trained and we don't need to reevaluate them anymore. Just take the model and make the predictions.

Answer (score 5):

I think the correct term in this context is 'Forecasting'.

A good explanation is: after you train and test your model, with the data that you already had (as the other ones said here before me), you want to predict future data, which is, I think, the trully interresting thing about recurrent networks.

So in order to make this, you need to start predicting the values from one day after your final date in your original dataset, using the model (which is trained with this past data). Once you predict this value, you do the same thing, but considering the last values predict, and so on.

The fact that you are using a prediction to make others predictions, implies that is much more difficult to get good results, so is common to try to predict short ranges of time.

The exact code that you need to perform to do this could vary, but I think that is the prime concept

In the link below, in the last part, in which is perform a forecast, the author show us a code and a explanation on how he did it.

https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks-74674e289816

I guess that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Since we don't have the future value with us while training the model, we just divide the data into train and test sets. Then we just imagine that test sets are the future values. We train our model using train set (and also usually a validation set). And after our model is trained, we test it using the test set to check our models performance.

Comment: Hi, if we just imagine that test sets are the future values and we have evaluated the model, how can we make predictions precisely with the results predicted after the test sets?